# How do I read dynamic data passed in an event handler in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically constructing table rows using jquery.

In the following chunk of code, how do I read `someValue` in method `prepareDiv()`?

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        var someValue = "DummyValue"
            html += '<tr id="resRowId' + rowindex + '" class="RsrvnRowClass">' +
                    '<td><a href="#" onclick="prepareDiv('+ someValue +');"><img src="../images/downarrow.jpg"></td></tr>';

        $('#resTable tr').first().after(html);
 });



function prepareDiv(value){
            alert("value" + value);
}
```

I am using IE. Upon calling `ready()`, I get error `DummyValue is undefined`.

Comment: Is this all the code?

Comment: No. Just chunk. I just simply want to pass the variable in method. I am missing some syntax I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're ending up with generated code that looks like this:

```
onclick="prepareDiv(DummyValue);"
```

The lack of quotes around `DummyValue` means that it's expected to be a variable, whereas you want it to be treated as a string literal, so you need to add the quotes yourself:

```
onclick="prepareDiv(\''+ someValue +'\');"
```

That should result in:

```
onclick="prepareDiv('DummyValue');"
```

Comment: It worked. If I am understanding right, it's enclosing   '+ someValue +'   inside   \'   and   \'

Answer (score 0):

You have fews syntax errors, try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var someValue = "DummyValue";
    html += '<tr id="resRowId' + rowindex + '" class="RsrvnRowClass">' +
            '<td>' + '<a href="#" onclick="prepareDiv(\''+ someValue +'\');"><img src="../images/downarrow.jpg" /></a></td></tr>';

    $('#resTable tr').first().after(html);
});
```

Comment: What exactly did you change? If it's just adding `' + '` between the `<td>` and `<a` then that's unnecessary. You've also removed the closing `</tr>` tag, making the HTML invalid.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Not his fault. I missed tr and it was not in the first place, I edited the question and added tr.

ps: How do you highlight code snippet in comments?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I just added fews ";" and fixed a concatenation problem. Btw I didn't add any ' + ' he eddited his post and removed it after my answer. However, thank you for the closing </tr>

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this...the dynamically added values should be appended to tbody

```
 var table = $("table tbody");

    table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            firstVal= $tds.eq(0).text(),
            secVal = $tds.eq(1).text(),
            thirdVal = $tds.eq(2).text();

        alert(firstVal);//etc..
    });
```

Comment: check whether u have referred js file at the top